# How do you access the Roles model from a custom user model in loopback using mysql datasource

Tags: loopbackjs

Windows 7 x64
loopback-cli 3.10

I have seen some other related questions but they have not solved my problem I have read the docs about how to gain access to an unrelated model within another model but in my case it will not work

I want to be able to access the role model inside the user model as in

```
let models = require('../../server/model-config.json');
let app = require('../../server/server.js');

module.exports = function (user) {

  let Role = app.models.Role;
  let RoleMapping = app.models.RoleMapping;

}
```

The above results in both being undefined.

As a boot script this works but I would prefer it all to be in the user model.

```
module.exports = function (app) {
  var User = app.models.user;
  var Role = app.models.Role;
  var RoleMapping = app.models.RoleMapping;


  RoleMapping.belongsTo(User);
  User.hasMany(RoleMapping, {foreignKey: 'principalId'});
  Role.hasMany(User, {through: RoleMapping, foreignKey: 'roleId'});
};
```

My relations are defined as

user.json

```
  "relations": {
    "roles": {
      "type": "hasMany",
      "model": "Role",
      "foreignKey": "principalId",
      "through": "RoleMapping"
    }
  }
```

Comment: You don't have to require a `server.js` file. You can get to a `Role` model via your `user` model - `user.app.models.Role`. You can also similarly get to your `RoleMapping` model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure exactly what you mean, but you can access once all the model is loaded. with following

```
let models = require('../../server/model-config.json');
let app = require('../../server/server.js');

module.exports = function (user) {
  app.on('started', function(){
     let Role = app.models.Role;
     let RoleMapping = app.models.RoleMapping;
  }); 
}
```

related link: [Loopback: How to add afterRemote of a model to another model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45586708/loopback-how-to-add-afterremote-of-a-model-to-another-model/45646248#45646248)

Comment: Yes that is what I was looking for, funny I just found that before reading this.  I would like to know if it is possible to get the above info just using relationships instead of 'started' as you are supposed to be able to access any related model.

Comment: As far as I know, the related models are used only to get the related records while querying.

Comment: Yes that is what I am trying to do, query the user/role information within the user model class. @Razmjo gave a solution that works I was just wondering if there was another way since the docs say you should be able to access the data within another model if you setup a relationship. Which I have tried unsuccessfully.